# Defining CSS keyframes during runtime

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I have a JS project, and I'm trying to define some keyframes for CSS3 animations. The problem is that the animation steps and their values (HTML object positions, etc.), should be filled by an external database (XML files). I load those XML files during runtime (so after the CSS files are loaded) and want to fill the keyframes at this time.

I looked for a way to solve it with HTML-elements' `style` property, but the only thing I found was this: https://css-tricks.com/animate-to-an-inline-style/

But this only helps me, if I have a fix start point and only 1 dynamic point (the end point). And that's not my situation. I have an unspecified amount of dynamic steps.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Generate style rules on the fly. You can add `style` elements dynamically.

Comment: As @T.J.Crowder says, update CSS on the fly, if a transition is set (or reset)  it should do the job

Comment: For that matter, you can also *modify* style rules on the fly.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder That's actually a very good idea! I have no idea how to do that right now, but I'll find that out. Thanks a lot!

Comment: :-) Starting point: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/styleSheets